# How to create a render tree form DOM and CSSOM?

Tags: html, css, dom, cssom

Everywhere it is written that the browser parses HTML into DOM and css into CSSOM and combines them to create a render tree.
There is official docs for creating [DOM](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html) and [CSSOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/) but I can't find any resources for combining them into render tree and creating a layout.
Does anybody have any idea or link to resources?

Comment: It sounds like you want to build a browser rendering engine. See: https://web.dev/critical-rendering-path-render-tree-construction/ for a graphical example of a render tree and the steps a browser will take to build one from the DOM and CSSOM.

Comment: @Rounin-StandingwithUkraine But That doesnot provide any guide for how to create a render tree like the mentioned link in the  post provide for DOM and CSSOM.

Comment: I suspect no guide is provided because building a browser rendering engine is not a trivial project. (Otherwise we'd have a lot more rendering engines...) I can only think of Webkit, Blink and Gecko - though there are, apparently, a handful of others. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_engine and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_browser_engines

Comment: Well, unfortunately I chose HTMl renderer as a college project and I aim to render basic html and css not everything in html only very basic and I am able to create a DOM(sort of) and working on CSSOM and I have no idea on how to proceed further to create a render tree and calculating layout and stuffs.
I don't think I can do much reading wikipedia.

Comment: Please take another look at the first illustration on https://web.dev/critical-rendering-path-render-tree-construction/ - I think it has enough for you to see what's happening. I'm sure you could put a list of rules together which determine whether any node in the DOM gets rendered or not and _how_ it gets rendered, given the constraints of the CSSOM. (Maybe write out a process chart to clarify things? That would be an excellent start to clarify your algorithm in your own head.) And, yes, you can learn a lot reading around the subject on wikipedia and elsewhere.

Comment: Building a browser engine is many man-years of effort. But having got a DOM and a CSSOM, the next step in the process  is to resolve the cascade and inheritance. At the end of that process, every element should have been assigned a computed value for every CSS property. Use the [Cascade spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-5/) as your guide to doing that.